# MongoDB: insert embedded document directly from another collection

Tags: mongodb

I have two collection:

```
// Profile
{
    _id: "12345",
    name: "max",
    country: "IT"
}

// Association
{
    _id: "43234",
    idclub: "1000",
    state: "0"
}
```

I want to insert a Profile on Association without searching it.
In my code i search for an Association but i don't have the object Profile in that moment, i just have its "id".

Is it possible to perform some kind of insert on collection A retrieving on the fly the object of collection B given it's own ID?

And then, is this a recurring practice? As i can find nothing it seems not properly the best way...

Thanks

Comment: do you mean something like the following as an end result ? 

{
    _id: "43234",
    idclub: "1000",
    state: "0",
    profile : {
         _id: "12345",
         name: "max",
         country: "IT"                  
     }
}

Comment: Yes, this it should be the result, just i wouldn't perform a find() to retrieve the Profile object...

Answer (score 0):

[Use findAndModify operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/)

```
     db.createCollection("Association"); 

     db.Association.insert({ _id : "43234", idclub:"1000",state:"0"});

     db.Association.findAndModify({ 
            query:{ _id:"43234" }, 
            update:{ $set:{ "profile":{ _id:"12345","name":"max","country":"IT" } } } 
    });

    db.Association.find();
```

> {"_id" : "43234", "idclub" : "1000", "state" : "0", "profile" : { "_id" : 
>              "12345", "name" : "max", "country" : "IT" } }

Comment: I only now see that you men't from another existing collection. 
i'll try it out later and modify the answer. sorry.

Comment: Yes, i don't know the values of profile's document.